# Deleting isolated storage directories in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to **delete the folder created in isolated storage.**
But i get a error of **"path must be a valid file name"**
My created file name is **"a07292011//time.Schedule"**.

So now i want to delete the folder and my code is:

**myStore.DeleteDirectory(selectedFolderName1 + "\\");**

Where **selectedFolderName1 = a07292011**

Comment: I hope, no need to append (+ "\\") with directory name. Because your going to delete folder itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method for deleting an isolated storage directory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="directoryName">Name of a directory to be deleted</param>
    public static void DeleteDirectory(string directoryName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile currentIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) && currentIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
                {
                    currentIsolatedStorage.DeleteDirectory(directoryName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something with exception
        }
    }
```

Get more details here

http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/11/isolated-storage-for-windows-phone-7/

Comment: is it currentIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName) returns true?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletedirectory.aspx check with that URL. **A directory must be empty before it is deleted. The deleted directory cannot be recovered once deleted.**

Comment: Thank for your help. Now i understand why it dont works already

Answer (score 5):

Here's my code to recursively delete foldersand theirfiles/subfolders from the isolated storage. It works on Windows Phone 8, too.

```
public static void CleanAndDeleteDirectoryRecursive(string directory)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (iso.DirectoryExists(directory))
        {
            string[] files = iso.GetFileNames(directory + @"/*");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                iso.DeleteFile(directory + @"/" + file);
                Debug.WriteLine("Deleted file: " + directory + @"/" + file);
            }

            string[] subDirectories = iso.GetDirectoryNames(directory + @"/*");
            foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
            {
                CleanAndDeleteDirectoryRecursive(directory + @"/" + subDirectory);
            }

            iso.DeleteDirectory(directory);
            Debug.WriteLine("Deleted directory: " + directory);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The directory you try to delete must be empty.

```
public void DeleteDirectory(string directoryName) {
try {
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) && currentIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName)) {
            var fn = isoFile.GetFileNames(string.Concat(directoryName, "\\*"));
            if (fn.Length > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < fn.Length; ++i)
                    isoFile.DeleteFile(string.Concat(directoryName, "\\", fn[i]));
            isoFile.DeleteDirectory(directoryName);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //implement some error handling
}
}
```