# Delete a directory from Isolated storage windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I created a directory named "MyFolder" and wrote some text files there. Now, I want delete that directory and I am using the following code:

```
 public void DeleteDirectory(string directoryName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile currentIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) && currentIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
                    {
                        currentIsolatedStorage.DeleteDirectory(directoryName);
                        textBox1.Text = "deleted"; 
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // do something with exception
            }
        }
```

I tried with

```
DeleteDirectory("MyFolder") 
DeleteDirectory("IsolatedStore\\MyFolder")
```

however it didn't delete that directory. Any idea to solve that?

Comment: did you delete everything in it first?  i'm not sure that is required... but it might be?

Comment: I first tried to delete files, but same results. not sure thats the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858050/deleting-isolated-storage-directories-in-windows-phone-7

I hope that it will help you

Answer (score 2):

Have you deleted all of the contents of that directory?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletedirectory(v=vs.80).aspx

says (although it isn't the windows phone version of the documentation):

> A directory must be empty before it is deleted. The deleted directory cannot be recovered once deleted.
>
> The [Deleting Files and Directories example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3852wf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) demonstrates the use of the DeleteDirectory method.