# How to Delete a Target Folder with it's All Files in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

I want to delete a folder with it's all files in windows phone. In the wp7.1 SDK, I just found follow APIs:

```
public void DeleteDirectory(string dir);
public void DeleteFile(string file);
```

If a folder is not empty and I call the `DeleteDirectory` method, there is an exception.
So, is there any way to delete the files in the target folder?

Comment: You can find answer there 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858050/deleting-isolated-storage-directories-in-windows-phone-7


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858050/deleting-isolated-storage-directories-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GetFileNames` get all the filenames in a directory. Then Iterate and delete all the files. thereafter when the folder is empty delete it too. I hope this helps.