# Clear Isolated Storage on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an application already published on the Windows Phone marketplace. Right now, I am working on an update (the first update actually) and I have changed the way data gets saved on the Isolated Storage. I am afraid that when I publish the update people will experience crashes because of the mess on Isolated Storage. Is there any way to delete ALL the data already stored on Isolated Storage and Isolated Storage Settings? I cant do it manually by deleting every single file because there are hundrends of files stored.

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the files if they exist when the application is first started? This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858050/deleting-isolated-storage-directories-in-windows-phone-7?rq=1

Comment: What I am asking is different. I simply want to delete everything stored including the Isolated Storage Settings. I cant just write code for maybe 500 text files and 1000 variables stored in the Isolated Storage settings. There must be a way to "empty all" with a single line of core

Comment: There is you just delete the directory the files are stored in.  You should only delete the files you created.  Do you really load hundreds of files, and if you do, then you know which files you want to delete.  You can use `GetFileNames()` or `DeleteFile(string file)` I suppose also.  If you want help we will need more detail otherwise we are just going around in circles.

Comment: Anyway I found the way to clear everything in isolated storage and isolated storage settings with few lines of code. Here is how i did it:

using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        store.Clear();
                    }

Comment: Good find on `store.Remove();` - I wasn't aware of that option!

Comment: Yes, it's store.Remove(); - I made a mistake above and wrote store.Clear(); - store.Clear(); is for IsolatedStorageSettings. It clears all the keys that exist and their values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put your files into one directory, why not call `DeleteDirectory()`? You'll want to put a check in there to make sure you're only deleting the old stuff (and ensure it only  happens once).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletedirectory(v=vs.105).aspx

**Update:**

To clear up any confusion, here is an example of using `DeleteDirectory`:

```
// Delete a specific directory.
string dirDelete = Path.Combine("MyApp1", "SubDir3");
try
{
   if (store.DirectoryExists(dirDelete))
   {
      store.DeleteDirectory(dirDelete);
   }
}
catch (IsolatedStorageException ex)
{
   sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: We normally like more detail then a single sentence and a link.

Comment: I'm sorry? I'm assuming the OP knows how to access Isolated Storage since he's apparently written to it. Doesn't seem necessary to simply copy/paste the sample from the link, but I guess I can.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already found out and comented above how to clear not just a single directory or file, but the entire data stored on isolated storage with a single line of code. It seems to be working so far.

Comment: I saw that, and agreed - your solution is better.

Comment: @lhan16 - Other people might not be as familar as the author is isolated storage on Windows Phone.